# Can AWS::SimpleEmailService messages be internationalized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

This is a simple question that I could not find the answer to scouring the docs of Amazon Simple Email Service and the AWS Ruby SDK (version 1) that I am using for my Rails app. I am asking on the site because my company doesn't have an account that allows for me to open support cases and additionally looking through the forums for AWS has not been productive at all. I am starting to think that maybe you can't internationalize but that can't be the case.

Has anyone used Amazon Simple Email Service and have I18n an email message?

Comment: See also about i18n: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76805394/ses-v2-email-templates-support-for-template-per-language-i18n.

Answer (score 1):

SES is just a very **Simple Email Service**. It doesn't know the language of the email you are sending or the language of the receiving party. How would it handle internationalization?

If you want to send emails in different languages you would need to modify the messages before you pass them to SES. I think there are some techniques to include multiple versions of an email message in different languages if you are sending HTML emails, but you would do that when you create the HTML, before SES is involved in the process.

SES just takes the HTML or text you give it and sends it to the recipient. It doesn't do any processing of the email message.